# Como enviar un parámetro por la url de retorno al guardar en spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, maven, thymeleaf

Hola soy nuevo en Spring Boot y tengo un problema quiero enviar de vuelta un parámetro del objeto que guardo para recargar la pagina con los datos de dicho objeto no se como hacerlo porque el dato es de tipo clase Activo una llave foránea, lo he hecho obteniendo con un get pero no funciona, espero que me puedan ayudar

```
package spi.mvc.com.data.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import spi.mvc.com.data.model.Activo;
import spi.mvc.com.data.model.Institucion;
import spi.mvc.com.data.model.RRHH;
import spi.mvc.com.data.model.RegistrodelSpi;
import spi.mvc.com.data.model.SpiDatos;
import spi.mvc.com.data.model.Zona;
import spi.mvc.com.data.service.IActivoService;
import spi.mvc.com.data.service.IInstitucionService;
import spi.mvc.com.data.service.IRRHHService;
import spi.mvc.com.data.service.IRegistroDelSpiService;
import spi.mvc.com.data.service.ISpiDatosService;
import spi.mvc.com.data.service.IZonaService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/views/Formulario")
public class FormularioController {
   @PostMapping("listaporspi/save")
    public String guardar(@Valid @ModelAttribute RegistrodelSpi registrodelspi, BindingResult result, Model model, RedirectAttributes alerta) {
        Activo activo= new Activo();
        activo= registrodelspi.getIdactivo();
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.print("Errores en el formulario por favor revice los campos");
            return "/views/Formulario/listaporspi/" + activo;
        }
        
        IRegistroDelSpiService.guardar(registrodelspi);
        System.out.print("REGISTRO GUARDADO CON EXITO");
        alerta.addFlashAttribute("success", "REGISTRO GUARDADO CON EXITO");
        return "redirect:/views/Formulario/listaporspi/" + activo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Estás usando algún gestor de plantillas, como por ejemplo Thymeleaf , y lo que quieres es retornar a una página que muestre ese dato activo usando una aplantilla?

Comment: Hola como estas Alex si estoy usando Thymeleaf, lo que quiero es que el dato activo me use para cargar la misma pagina donde estoy trabajando , es decir ese dato lo uso para cagar datos de una base de datos que están filtrados por ese dato activo